# IIS configuration not to redirect to default.aspx

Tags: iis-7, redirection

When i write http://www.spotagel.com it redirects to http://www.spotagel.com/default.aspx, 
i tried some method to stop this, but they casued infinite loops. how can i do this without infinite loops

Comment: For future reference it would be helpful for those tying to help you if you stated what methods you've tried to rectify a problem. This will help people get a better understanding of your problem, and helps you get better information.

Answer (score 1):

IIS isn't redirecting to default.aspx, IIS is being told that default.aspx is the preferred page to load first. To change this you need to change the default document property of the webpage you're working with.

See : http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument

Comment: for example when you type http://www.winhost.com ( it is also a as.net driven when you look at source) there is no change on adress bar occurs , i mean no cahnge to http://www.winhost.com/default.aspx o r whatever is default document